# Application silent exit on VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, crash

I'm on windows 7 x64. Using C++ in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010.

When I run any own application with VS after, aprox, 15 seconds the application is forced to exit. No messages, no Exceptions, no nothing. It doesn't matter how simple it is the application.

After a couple of weeks reviewing and commenting my code, I tried by reinstalling my S.O. and programs, thinking in some driver update or something similar. Whatever it was should solve my problem. That didn't solve the problem either.

You can see an example in
https://twitter.com/#!/nachovall/status/176996407780188160/photo/1/large

Note that it hasn't empty the buffer!! Just crazy.

I'm thinking in some whatchdog problem. I mean some, windows 7 issue which causes a given application to exit after some seconds.

The worst thing is that I have no idea about how to search this in Google. 'Silent crash'? It's not crashing, just exiting.

Well, if anyone knows what the problem is... you know.

By the way, I did a whole hardware analysis looking for some CPU or Memory problem. Nothing found.

Even more. I run the debug. I set a breakpoint in the first line of code. The application is doing nothing. Just waiting me to step over in the debugger. After 15 seconds, the application ends. Cool ha?

Comment: Interesting question, but this might not be the best place to ask it.

Comment: What about other applications or other languages? Does for example a simple `C#` program run normally? Does writing the same in `MASM` also cause this behavior? What if you attach the debugger to it?

Comment: This only happens on C++ projects. With c# or VB everithing works fine. The program, the debugger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, all night awake but finally found.

It was the antivirus program. Avast version 7.0.1407. When I disable it, everything get sense again.

It's been 2 weeks. 2 large and exhausting weeks. Anyone who's using this antivirus, please be aware.